# How can I start an Activity from a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I would like to start an `Activity` from a `Fragment` when I press a button on the last one but I am getting a blank layout instead of the layout that is associated to the `Activity`.

I call the `Fragment` from `MainActivity.class` like this:

```
FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContent,new FragmentMain()).commit();
```

And on `FragmentMain` class I have an `onClick` method like follows:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FinalClass.class);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
}
```

but the result is a blank layout and no errors are shown on the logcat. I have searched on the web for similar behaviours and I found some solutions that did not resolve my problem:

- From [In Fragment on back button pressed Activity is blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340303/in-fragment-on-back-button-pressed-activity-is-blank):

I do not have any method `addToBackStack()` on my project so this solution does not work for me.

- From [How do I start an activity from within a Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074608/how-do-i-start-an-activity-from-within-a-fragment):

`getActivity().startActivity(myIntent)` is the accepted answer.

The ways that they use to start the Activity from the Fragment does not change from the way I am using.

- From [Starting Activity by intent from Fragment starts blank Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154979/starting-activity-by-intent-from-fragment-starts-blank-activity):

Any of the solutions provided worked for me.

**P.S:** I have declared the `Activity` on the `Manifest.xml` file:

```
<activity
      android:name=".FinalClass"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:label="Final Class"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

**P.S.2:** Do not doubt to ask if you need more code (I tried to simplify it to focus on the problem).

What can I do to avoid that the `Activity` gives to me a blank layout instead of the layout associated to that `Activity`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do have any views in the layout of `FInalClass` activity?

Comment: Just a side note, not sure if doing 'getActivity().startActivity()' from a fragment is a good practice. I'd suggest using an interface that your activity will implement, then call a method on the interface from your fragment. Then start your activity from your activity. Don't think it's related to your problem though..

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid I have the following: `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View inflaterFinalClass = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_final_class, null); return inflaterFinalClass;`

Comment: `FinalClass` is Fragment?..show layout code for `activity_final_class`

Comment: @vkislicins I suppose that you would want to put: "Then start your activity from your interface". Why do you think is not a good practice? (before I had only `startActivity` instead of `getActivity().startActivity`, I have changed it as suggested on the questions related.

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid No, it is an Activity.

Comment: @Error404 Your activity implements your interface, so by calling a method on your interface you are effectively calling a method in your activity, which will in turn start another activity. Hence starting activity from activity. I think it's cleaner that way, activity changes are at the top level, easier to maintain the code. Also fragments are effectively children of the activity and exist within the activity, so by starting an activity from fragment it's like a child ordering a parent :)

Comment: @vkislicins Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your layout in activity like this in `onCreate`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_final_class);
}
```

dont use `onCreateView` for activity

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start a activity from Fragment using fragment instance.but you can start a activity using **fragment container activity instance**. 
For eg: Let say **Activity A** having **Fragment Abc**, so you have to use the instance of Activity A not Fragment abc.

By doing this there will be **no effect** in your previous fragment ,because it seat top of your Activity, instead of replacing or adding existing Fragment. If you want do some changes in existing Fragment then you have to override **onActivityResult**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

:)GlbMP

Answer (score 0):

You can use onCreateView method then use this code it will also help...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FinalClass.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);

// Closing all the Activities
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

// Add new Flag to start new Activity
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: This does not have any changes. I got the solution. Anyway, thanks! :)

Comment: use once again this will also run perfectly i am using this

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution. I was using the wrong onCreate method.

Before, I had:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
       final View inflaterFinalClass = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_final_class, null); 
       return inflaterFinalClass;
```

but I should use:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_final_class);
}
```

So, in conclusion, I was using the onCreate method for a Fragment instead of the onCreate method for an Activity.

Comment: Thats what i answered

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid Oh, sorry. I was writting it and did not saw your answer but your comment points me out to get the solution when I realized that it could be the problem on the way I was creating the Activity.

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid Yes, I could not still accept. Now I did it. Anyway, I will maintain my answer. Maybe it can help more people also.